# Fill column with maximum/last value from another column

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

How can I get the result as in example with `ARRAYFORMULA` up to *last filled cell A*?

[image: Example]

I can do it with formula in *cell C1* `=MAX(B$1:B1)` but in that case have to copy the formula in each cell in turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C2 try:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(row(A2:A) <= max(if(not(isblank(A2:A)), row(A2:A))),vlookup(row(A2:A),filter({row(A2:A),B2:B},len(B2:B)),2),))
```

See [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Itt0foGsiyh3TCgzBkp-XwHHHHbOXVO6PrbSdXGcPh4/edit?usp=sharing) for an example.